# How to display random names from checked boxes / windows forms / c#

Tags: c#, winforms, random, checkbox

at the beginning I will say that I am a beginner in programming, but I want to make a program for work that will randomize the name of an employee. Only names that are checked in the checkbox. It currently randomizes me either from all names or from the most recently selected ones. Names so far marked as: N1, N2, N3, N4, N5:
My code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MNW_v._1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
      
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void N1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void N2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void N3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void N4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void N5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] tablica = new string[] { N1.Text, N2.Text, N3.Text, N4.Text, N5.Text };
            
            Random rn = new Random();
            int obj = rn.Next(0, tablica.Length);
            Console.Write(obj);
            if (N1.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(N1.Text);
            }
            else if (N2.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(N2.Text);
            }
            else if (N3.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(N3.Text);
            }
            else if (N4.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(N4.Text);
            }
            else if (N5.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(N5.Text);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

I've already tried to create an additional class, but it seems that then checking the boxes does not affect the operation of the program.

Comment: What is the problem with the program?

Comment: So you want to display names randomly? Am I correct? Like this: N2, N4, N1, N3, N5?

Comment: No, just one of them. For example: I have selected N1, N2 , N3, N4, N5 - and only one name should be drawn for me, for example N3,

Comment: Oh, got you idea. Just a sec, will write an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather have an array of `CheckBox`es, not their `Text`s:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // So we have all CheckBoxes of interest in the collection (array)
  // we can query
  var boxes = new CheckBox[] {
    N1, N2, N3, N4, N5
  };

  // How many checked CheckBoxes do we have
  int count = boxes.Count(box => box.Checked);

  // If we have at least one checked CheckBox, we can get random one
  string randomName = count > 0
    ? boxes.Where(box => box.Checked).ElementAt(Random.Shared.Next(count)).Text
    : ""; // If none of boxes has been checked 

  MessageBox.Show(randomName);      
}
```

If `Random.Shared` is *not supported* by your version of .Net, you can use a field:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static readonly Random random = new Random();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var boxes = new CheckBox[] {
    N1, N2, N3, N4, N5
  };

  int count = boxes.Count(box => box.Checked);

  string randomName = count > 0
    ? boxes.Where(box => box.Checked).ElementAt(random.Next(count)).Text
    : ""; 

  MessageBox.Show(randomName);      
}
```

Comment: Shows: Error CS0103 The name 'random' does not exist in the current context and And I'm not sure where to put the variable

Comment: Never mind, it works :D I didn't type a single line earlier, I'm glad you don't have to write out the whole list of names. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest way I could come up with to solve the problem:

```
private Random rn = new Random();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox[] tablica =
        new[] { N1, N2, N3, N4, N5 }
            .Where(n => n.Checked)
            .ToArray();

    if (tablica.Any())
    {
        CheckBox cb = tablica[rn.Next(0, tablica.Length)];
        MessageBox.Show(cb.Text);
    }
}
```

It simply create an array of checkboxes that are checked from the initial set of 5 checkboxes. It then ensures at least one is in the array and displays the message for one at random.

---

Here is a slightly less efficient (although with 5 checkboxes the difference is negligible) way to do it that I think is slightly neater:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb =
        new[] { N1, N2, N3, N4, N5 }
            .Where(n => n.Checked)
            .OrderBy(x => rn.Next())
            .FirstOrDefault();

    if (cb != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(cb.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to pick one of the checked names at random.

The other answers mostly iterate a list or array ***every time*** a new value is picked. This one iterates the checkboxes ***only once*** to attach the `CheckedChanged` event. (This isn't such a big distinction with only 5 to pick from, but think *scale!*)

Now the checked state is observable, allowing a list of currently-checked checkboxes to be maintained. The change event is handled by adding or removing the sender from this list.

Then, when you click the Pick button, the `_random` (which is a *member* field, not instantiated each time) is called to to pick an *index* guaranteed to be less than the `Count` of this list-of-checked-checkboxes.

[image: screenshot]

---

For example, this code as shown will produce **N4, N3, N2, N4, N2...** and so on.

For testing purposes, seeding the `Random` with a value of 2 when instantiated ensures the *same* pseudo-random sequence is generated every time. (Otherwise, the default seed value of [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=net-7.0) is derived from the system clock and produces a new sequence every time this code is run.)

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() =>  InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        buttonPick.Click += button1_Click;
        foreach (CheckBox checkbox in Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(_ => _ is CheckBox))
        {
            checkbox.CheckedChanged += onAnyCheckedChanged;
        }
    }
    List<CheckBox> _checkedCheckboxes = new List<CheckBox>();
    private void onAnyCheckedChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(sender is CheckBox checkbox)
        {
            if(checkbox.Checked) _checkedCheckboxes.Add(checkbox);
            else _checkedCheckboxes.Remove(checkbox);
            Text = $"{_checkedCheckboxes.Count} Selected";
        }
    }
    Random _random = new Random(2);
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BeginInvoke(() =>   // Don't block the click event
        {
            if(_checkedCheckboxes.Count == 0){
                MessageBox.Show("Check some names first");
            }
            else{
                int randomIndex = _random.Next(0, _checkedCheckboxes.Count);
                MessageBox.Show($"Picked: {_checkedCheckboxes[randomIndex].Text}");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates an array, generates a random number, then ignores both and simply chooses the first selected name. What you need to do is create an List of selected names

```
 var names = new List<string>();
 if (N1.Checked) names.Add(N1.Text);
 if (N2.Checked) names.Add(N2.Text);
 ...
```

now generate a random index

```
 Random rn = new Random();
 int obj = rn.Next(0, names.Count);
```

now use that

```
    Console.WriteLine(names[obj]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code should help you:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Random random;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
    }

    private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> namesList = new List<string>();
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = control as CheckBox;
            if (checkBox != null && checkBox.Checked)
            {
                namesList.Add(checkBox.Name);
            }
        }
        if (namesList.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Check at least one option!");
        }
        else
        {
            int randomIndex = random.Next(0, namesList.Count);
            MessageBox.Show(namesList[randomIndex]);
        }
    }
}
```

Quick explanation:

1. About `new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());` initialisation. This code provides different random values every time you start your application.
2. I get all controls of form using `Controls` property. That way you can create any amount of checkboxes on form without editing this block of code.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Why introduce the `Controls` collection? The OP doesn't use it and for all you know they have a thousand other checkboxes on the form.

Comment: You're right. However, the number of employees tends to change and I don't think the OP will rewrite the program every time someone is fired or hired. That is why I wrote a code that allows you to complete the task with any number of workers. And if using the `Controls` collection is a problem for you, then you can simply put all the necessary `CheckBoxes` in the `Panel` and then iterate over `Panel.Controls`.

Comment: If the number of employees change then the OP would dynamically create the controls. That is the perfect time to store the checkboxes in an array to be used later. Iterating through the `Controls` collection is not the way to go. I would ask any junior developer to go back and rewrite the code if they wrote it this way. It's just a future bug waiting to happen.